# Pull and display live frames from an unknown video capture device using Java and DirectShow

Tags: java, video, directshow, video-capture

I am working on a a video review project in Java.
I am improving upon an existing and extremley outdated piece of software that runs on a Windows 2000 machine that has been turned into a DVR.  The machine has 4 capture devices, each capture device has 4 inputs.  I have had no issues taking already saved video and playing it back.  I have a $0 budget and have to use already existing technologies.
That being said, I am also forced to use DirectShow Java wrapper, which seems to work the best.
The problem I am facing now, is I am not able to get DirectShow to reconize the capture devices on the machine, but I am very new to the DirectShow API and have only attempted making a call to queryDevices().  This has no issue finding my webcam or TV tuner on my PC, but fails to find anything on the DVR PC.

The name of the capture card is Moab-5 v1.10.  It is pretty old and the company that originally made the device no longer supports it or the software since they have moved to bigger and way better things.

I do not know much about the capture device, I am looking for information about it and how it works, which would help alot.

Anyone have any bright ideas how I can pull video from this using DirectShow or anything else for that matter?
Any other way I can approach this challenge?  Other media frameworks I can explore? I have tried most of them and this is the only one that has worked the best.

I am open to trying anything, but want to stick with Java in the end, it's what I am good with.

Comment: You can use the GraphEdit tool from the MS SDK to list video capture devices (without having to do any programming). Does your desired capture device show up under the video capture device?

Answer (score 1):

Run [GraphEditPlus](http://www.infognition.com/GraphEditPlus/) on that PC, find in the filters list your capture device, add it to an empty graph, right click its output pin, choose Render and you'll got a graph ready to show the video. You can then generate code (see File menu) and see how it's built.